# Issue with ZK selectbox setSelectedIndex

Tags: drop-down-menu, zk

my code:

```
public void doAfterCompose(Window comp) throws Exception {
    super.doAfterCompose(comp); 
    ListModel model = new ListModelList(new Integer[]{0 ,1 ,2 });
    DsaDocumentBaseConfigSignsCountNum.setModel(model);
    DsaDocumentBaseConfigSignsCountNum.setSelectedIndex(2);  
}
```

Selectbox doesn´t show anything selected.
i can´t figure out why setSelectedIndex doesn´t work. Any ideas? Am i missing something? Zul page is linked by id, and i am using @Wire for controller.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved . I used different component, combobox specifically.